X86-64 assembly syscall statx
I have a problem with _statxFlow. I try to call statx and save GID in uidGidRecieved. I don't know what the problem is (well, besides that _print is not suited for integers, but that's I have already fixed).
Here is my code:
section .data
       gid db "GID: ", 0
       nl db 10

section .bss
       uidGidRecieved resb 128

section .text
global _start

_start:
       lea rdi, [rsp+16] ;temporary saving "path" for statx
       call _statxFlow
       call _printGid:

_statxFlow:

       mov rax, 332 ; call statx
       mov rsi, rdi ;passing path to statx
       mov rdi, 0   ; from current dir
       mov rdx, 0x100 ;flags
       mov r10, 0x00000010 ;mask
       mov r8, uidGidRecieved ;buff
       syscall
       ret

_printGid:
       mov rax, gid
       call _print

       mov rax, uidGidRecieved
       call _print
       ret

_print:
       push rax
       mov rbx, 0
_LoopPrint:
       inc rax
       inc rbx
       mov cl, [rax]
       cmp cl, 0
       jne _LoopPrint

       mov rax, 1
       mov rdi, 1
       pop rsi
       mov rdx, rbx
       syscall
       ret


What symptoms are you seeing that indicate a problem?  i.e. what problem are you trying to fix?  A pointer in R8 looks right.  mov reg, label is inefficient but works for most ways of building a program; How to load address of function or label into register .  What does strace ./a.out say?
